# Is it safe to pass a lambda function that goes out of scope to a std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Considering the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::thread t;
    {
        auto my_lambda = []{
           int idx = 0;
           while (true) {
               std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
               std::cout << idx ++ << std::endl;
           } 
        };
        t = std::thread(my_lambda);
    }
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Is it safe that the thread runs a lambda function that goes out of scope?

I saw that the constructor of `std::thread` takes an universal reference for the input function `Function&& f` and that lambdas are translated into structs. So if the instance of the struct is instantiated inside the scope, the thread will be running the `operator()` of a dangling reference.

```
{
    struct lambda_translated { void operator()(){ ... } };
    lambda_translated instance;
    t = std::thread(instance);
}
```

However I'm not sure that my reasoning is correct.

Side question: does the behavior change if I declare the lambda as an R-value inside the `std::thread` constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::thread t;
    {
        
        t = std::thread([]{
           int idx = 0;
           while (true) {
               std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
               std::cout << idx ++ << std::endl;
           } 
        });
    }
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is save to pass the lambda (the thread will move it, constructor 3 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)). What is not be safe is passing references to local variables, so always capture variables in lambda by value when passing it to a thread. (For larger datastructures this may be a std::shared_ptr to that data, but also capture that by value).

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes the lambda does not capture anything as in the examples I posted

Comment: `std::thread` moves or copies by value the given arguments so it should be fine.

Comment: I noticed that you didn't capture anything yet just giving a heads up for the future :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Thank you. Now I also understand the Function&& f must have a non-deleted copy constructor!

Comment: You are welcome there usually is a lot to find on cppreference. And its a  bit more accessible then the actual standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a summary of the comments:

The lambda is copied (or moved if declared in-place), so you won't have problems.

You have to worry about the captures: do not capture by reference objects that can go out of the scope, or if you pass objects that can be deleted during thread execution (even if copied, think about a raw pointer to an object).

---

As an extension, same applies if you use `std::bind` to pass a method and the object goes out of scope or it is deleted.